# Multiple root element (DataContractSerializer)

Tags: c#, sdk, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to deserialize file by using DataContractSerializer. I have such class:

```
[DataContract]
public class kontenerUstawienia
{
    [DataMember]
    public int[] stanGry;
    [DataMember]
    public int maxSize;
    [DataMember]
    public int[] stanOpcji;

    [DataMember]
    public int numerFlagi1;
    [DataMember]
    public int numerFlagi2;

    public kontenerUstawienia()
    {
    }

(...)
}
```

Inside, after saving serialized class instance to the file, I read the file and try to deserialize:

```
try
{
    zapiszObiektUstawien((kontenerUstawienia)deserializer.ReadObject(strumien));
}

catch (SerializationException e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n++++++\n" + 
    e.Message 
    + "\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
}
```

catch prints me:

```
++++++
There was an error deserializing the object of type
WindowsPhoneGame1.kontenerUstawienia. There are multiple root elements. Line 1,
position 599.
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Here is code that I serialize and save:

```
public void zapiszDoPliku(string sciezkaDoPliku, IsolatedStorageFile katalog)
{
    IsolatedStorageFileStream strumien = katalog.CreateFile(sciezkaDoPliku); // tworzenie pliku

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    StreamReader r  = new StreamReader(ms);

    DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(kontenerUstawienia));

    serializer.WriteObject(ms, this);

    ms.Position = 0;

    string daneDoZapisania = r.ReadToEnd();

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(daneDoZapisania);

    strumien.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    ms.Close();
    strumien.Close();
}
```

EDIT2:

File saved:
[File is here](http://paste.org/62890)

Comment: Please show the code that performs the serialization.

Comment: I've added serialization code

Comment: Most likely you write to the `IsolatedStorageFile` multiple times without deleting the old content.

Comment: Can you show the serialized content (string) that you are trying to deserialize?

Comment: Yes, the file has wrong structure, but why? I've added it to message

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the file was empty before writing?

Comment: I'm using CreateFile, not OpenFile, so I think, it erases it.

Comment: Use Flush() method before Close() stream object.